# Maven build fails cause javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I get an error while building a maven project (Java 8 update 40), but there should not be a javadoc problem, cause there is no javadoc:

```
[INFO] Constructing Javadoc information...
[INFO] 1 error
...
An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
...
[INFO] [ERROR] bad class file: ...
...
undeclared type variable: D
...
```

Here the method:

```
public static <D extends Displayable> Provider<D> forDisplayable(
        final Function<D, Type> function) {
    return new Provider<>(d -> d.getDisplayName(), function);
}
```

What is going on?

Part of POM:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.3</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
```

Comment: Can you post part of (what you can share) the POM file?

Comment: Could you share the complete logs and corresponding config or class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208139/javadoc-undeclared-type-variable), but got no useful answer. In case you don't get one either here is what you can do to make it work:

- either downgrade Java to 1.8.0_20 (maybe something above 1.8.0_60 will work; 1.8.0_31, 1.8.0_40, 1.8.0_45, 1.8.0_60 all don't work for me)
- or add `<maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>` in the properties of the *pom.xml* to disable JavaDoc

Comment: I add the property and it works, but is there another way as skipping javadoc?

Comment: @HolgerS I guess you could always stop using bleeding edge features like [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)...